# Is it possible to make jdeb maven plugin retrieve all maven dependencies and include it into deb file?

Tags: maven, maven-2

Currently we use shaded jar for it. Trying to find a way to do it in more straightforward way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to download your dependencies to your selected folder, e.g.:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependency</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        <execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This way, I copied all dependencies into the `target/lib` folder. Later, you simply use this path inside `<configuration>` tag of the `jdeb` plugin, like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.vafer</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdeb</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            ...
            <dataSet>
                <data>
                    <type>directory</type>
                    <src>${project.build.directory}/lib</src>
                    <mapper>
                        <type>perm</type>
                        <prefix>{newpath}</prefix>
                    </mapper>
                </data>
            </dataSet>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```